# variables in loop for cycle with javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I simplify my problem to a minimum because in reality my code is very long and complex to explain.

I have two text input fields, in the first field I can insert a series of values, while the second field receives the values of the first field and compares them with those it already has. if there are double values the function warns and the user can choose whether to overwrite them or delete them, otherwise the value is added.

I want to do this through a for loop.

```js
function prova() {
  var stringa_valoredainserire = document.getElementById("valoredainserire").value;
  var stringa_valoredacambiare = document.getElementById("valoredacambiare").value;
  var stringa_valoredacambiare2 = document.getElementById("valoredacambiare");
  mioarray = stringa_valoredainserire.split("; ");
  var i, len, text;
  //inizio ciclo for                                                       
  for (i = 0, len = mioarray.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {
    if (stringa_valoredacambiare.indexOf(mioarray[i]) !== -1) {
      if (confirm('il valore ' + mioarray[i] + ' esiste, ok per sovrascriverlo, annulla per cancellarlo')) {
        stringa_valoredacambiare2.value = stringa_valoredacambiare.replace(mioarray[i], mioarray[i]);
      } else {
        stringa_valoredacambiare2.value = stringa_valoredacambiare.replace(mioarray[i] + '; ', '');
      }
    } else {
      stringa_valoredacambiare2.value = stringa_valoredacambiare2.value + mioarray[i] + '; ';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="valoredainserire" value="" type="text">
<input id="valoredacambiare" value="pere; cipolle; mele; " type="text" readonly>
<input type="button" onclick="prova();" value="Prova">
```

the problem is that if the values to be entered in the first input field are equal to the values of the second, if I wanted to delete them, the function only deletes the last one, because it is the last variable that keeps it in memory.

how can I remedy this situation? some idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OliverRadini my for loop does not sequence the ids of the elements, but the array of the value of the first input... or at least that's what I believe :)

Comment: Find the index of the value in the array, then assign it the new value

Comment: @Huangism how can I do?

Comment: When you find the duplicate in the existing array, get the index of the existing value `indexOf("value")`, then just use `splice` to remove the item or assign the item a different value based on your need. Just google "javascript array [whatever you need]"